having $H \leq Z \leq G$, and knowing every class of $\mid G:Z \mid$ and $\mid Z:H \mid$, how can I find $G/H$?
I'm just wondering if there's some shortcut to calculating all the classes of $\mid G:H \mid$, knowing all the intermediate classes, $\mid G:Z \mid$ and $\mid Z:H \mid$. In particular, I want to know in the case where $G=\{(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^4:a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ or } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $Z = \mathbb{Z}^4$ and $H=\{(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{Z}^4:a+b+c+d \text{ is even}\}$.
I know for this particular case, $\mid G:Z \mid = 2$, and the classes are just: $\mathbb{Z}^4$ and $(\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2})^4$, where this last one, I should clarify, means vectors of order $4$ where all the components are integers plus a half. In the case of $\mid Z:H \mid$, well the index is $2$ again, and the classes are $\mathbb{Z}^4$ where the sum of the components is even and $\mathbb{Z}^4$ where the sum of the components is odd.
Can I use this information of intermediate classes to find all the classes of $\mid G:H \mid$? Which will then help me find $G/H$. I know the index is going to be $4$ but I don't know what exactly are the classes, and I kind of need that to find the quotient.

What are the groups' operations?

Vector addition.@Shaun

In general, if ${g_i}$ is a complete set of coset representatives for $Z$ in $G$, and ${z_j}$ is a complete set of coset representatives for $H$ in $Z$, then ${g_iz_j}$ is a complete set of representatives for $H$ in $G$. Is that what you are asking?

In your example $|G:H|=4$ and $|G:Z|=|Z:H|=2$, so you are asking how to compute the classes of $4$ knowing the classes of $2$ and $2$. What is that supposed to mean? The word `classes' in group theory usually refers to conjugacy classes, but your groups are abelian, so all of the conjugacy classes are singletons.
